# SQL Syntax error when using INTERSECT in UPDATE query

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have two queries running, one to find matches within a database, and a second query which then updates a column in the database. The queries are exactly the same, except one is a SELECT statement and the other is an UPDATE statement. The syntax in the WHERE clause is the exact same in both queries, and the SELECT statement finds all the right results with no problems or syntax errors. The second query gives this error:

> ERROR: near "INTERSECT": syntax error

:

This is the SELECT query:

```
SELECT * FROM StudentInfo 
    WHERE FirstLanguageToOffer = 'French' 
    OR SecondLanguageToOffer = 'French'
    OR ThirdLanguageToOffer = 'French'
    INTERSECT 
    SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE Gender = 'Female'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE MaxPartners > CurrentPartners
    INTERSECT
    SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE Preference ='Male' OR Preference = 'It doesnt matter'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE LanguageToPractice ='English'
    ORDER BY Priority
    LIMIT 1;
```

This is the UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE StudentInfo SET CurrentPartners = CurrentPartners -1  
    WHERE FirstLanguageToOffer = 'French' 
    OR SecondLanguageToOffer = 'French'
    OR ThirdLanguageToOffer = 'French'
    INTERSECT 
    SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE Gender = 'Female'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE MaxPartners > CurrentPartners
    INTERSECT
    SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE Preference ='Male' OR Preference = 'It doesnt matter'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE LanguageToPractice ='English'
    ORDER BY Priority
    LIMIT 1;
```

Does anyone know what could cause this problem? Are INTERSECT operations not supported in UPDATE queries? I am using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INTERSECT` doesn't have any meaning in terms of updates. Your `SELECT` query is actually *five* independent queries being run simultaneously in order to return the intersection of the five independent result sets. Since `UPDATE` doesn't generate a result set, it's an error to try to intersect its non-result with the results of `SELECT` queries.

It does seem like your original purpose would be better served with a single `SELECT` query with a complex `WHERE` clause, since each of the five queries is running against the same table checking different conditions.

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you, that makes sense. I'll re-write the statement so it's a single WHERE. Out of interest, could I use INTERSECT if I had multiple UPDATE operations?

Comment: No. `INTERSECT`, `UNION`, `EXCEPT`, and so on are mathematical operations which work only on sets, and the way you describe a set in SQL is via `SELECT`. Trying to take the intersection of non-sets is like trying to multiply sentences.